# JS link - Change Cell bg color based on text value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a task list in Sharepoint with a column titled "Health". This column contains a drop-down list of text values "Green", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue" & "Grey".

I'd like to create a JS link file to render the cell background color only based on these text values.

I did this successfully using a script editor webpart, but I'd rather achieve this with a JS link instead (one less webpart on my pages).

Below is what I inserted into my script editor webpart. I need something similar in the form of a JS link file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Blue')");
        $Text.css("background-color", "#0000FF");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Green')");
        $Text.css("background-color", "Green");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Canceled')")
        $Text.css("background-color", "#e18620");
    });
</script>
```

I've tried multiple snippets from various threads and nothing has worked. All of my other JS files work so it's operator error either or bad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var fieldContext = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Available field on List View 
        "Health": { "View": fieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
})();  
// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function fieldTemplate(ctx) { 
    var health = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    return "<span style='background-color: "+health+";'>" + health + "</span>";
}
</script>
```

[image]

Refer to: [Colored output in list view with JSLink](https://olafd.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/colored-output-in-list-view-with-jslink/)